# Firefox displaying extra <strong> tags, but there not in the html source?

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser

My website in acting stangely while being viewed in firefox so I started debugging and found firefox only is adding extra `<strong>` tags in my code, all empty?

Any ideas?

http://allia.honestideas.co.uk/

Comment: Looks like spam to me, more than an actual question.

Comment: You should add the relevant code here.

Comment: Are you for real? Its a question mate.... my would I put up a development sub domain as spam? I can't post in the code for my whole site now can I? I think the problem is being caused by a conflict in plugins or jquery files...

Comment: Forget it I'll talk my visit elsewhere... Great service stackoverflow...

Comment: It's obviously an actual question, based on the fact that visiting the given URL produces the described behavior. Don't just assume 'cause there's a URL that something nefarious is going on.

Comment: Yea, I observed the strong tags, but no clue what's going on there.

Comment: you should add code if you want help.... if the people here would be able to solve problems without seeing any code maybe they were doing another job!

Comment: I guess Lorenzo has edited out the link... so I'll never know... [ooh, didnt know you could get revisions back]

Comment: No I did not.. There was'nt any link when I started to edit

Comment: It was removed by the author in a previous edit

Comment: **I don't see it.** I opened Chrome and Firefox side by side, and I don't see any differences. Can you post an edited screenshot that shows the difference or something? Or at least give us a general idea of *where* the problem is occurring?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue with Firefox 3.6 on Mac. Removed all references to JavaScript and still had this problem. Only add-on is Firebug. Tried on multiple computers, all produce the same issue.

Comment: The issue was that there were unclosed/mis-nested `<strong>` tags earlier in the source. Other browsers closed them properly and figured things out but Firefox freaked out. Kudos to Safari's inspector for reporting the problem. Should have also come up on [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Here's to always validating your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time the generated markup differs from the markup retrieved from the server (i.e., the markup you get when doing "View Source"), JavaScript is involved. The only way the structure of the page can be different from the markup you wrote is if JavaScript is making changes.

In this case, the extra `<strong>` tags all seem to be clustered immediately around the slider markup. I can't find any obvious explanation in `slider.js` but it's also not a plugin I'm intimately familiar with. Removing `slider.js` from the page entirely should solve the problem, but of course you then won't have the functionality you want. Perhaps a different plugin can offer the same functionality without the unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is not adding anything. If you look at 'view source', there are no strong tags in there. So what debugger are you using? I'd bet the debugger is inserting something.

Answer (score 0):

In firebug, I see a strong syntax in the code

```
#mainContent strong, #mainContent label
```

may be this causing some issues. I am not sure too.